# Alternative for Deprecated DBCollection.save() method

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

After upgrading mongo dependency, the `save()` method no longer exists. What's the alternative?

Old:

```
        DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject(items);
        DBCollection dbCollection = mongoOperations.getCollection(collection);
        dbCollection.save(dbObject);
```

New:

```
        DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject(items);
        MongoCollection mongoCollection = mongoOperations.getCollection(collection);
        mongoCollection.save(dbObject); //save() does not exist
```

Comment: MongoDB Java Driver's [Write Operations](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/perform-write-operations/) has sample code to work with the newer driver software. `save` is deprecated in the newer versions of MongoDB.

Comment: My concern is that I would basically need to package a lock/transaction containing a `find` followed by an `update`/`insert` to avoid any concurrency issues

Comment: You can try using update with upsert option.

Comment: There is no `upsert` in the java interface

Comment: upsert is part of the update method; for example [db.collection.updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#syntax) has the _upsert_ option.

Comment: I've given it my best shot, can you please correct it? At the moment `new Document(entry.getValue()),` is giving an error